# In there anyway i can make my multiple exception into a new py file?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am new to python and still learning about it. Is there any way I can modularize all the exception by making the multiple exception into 1 new python file? Below is my code.

```
class hypeaf:
    def hi():
        4/0
if __name__ == "__main__":
     try:
        h=hypeaf
        h.hi()
     except ZeroDivisionError: 
         print("zero")
     except FileNotFoundError:
         print("one")
     except FileExistsError:
         print("two")
     except Exception:
         print("three")
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by making the excetions into one new file? What do you want to archive?

Comment: what i mean is by making all the exception into one new python file, so whatever error occur in this original file i just have to pass into the other python file that contain all this exceptions. So when i write a new python code that require those exception, i can just pass the error into the exceptions file rather than write all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean.  If you're saying you want to only handle errors in a separate file to help make your code easier to read then you should be able to do the following:

Main.py:

```
from ErrorHandling import ErrorHandler

class hypeaf:
    def hi():
        4/0
if __name__ == "__main__":
     try:
        h=hypeaf
        h.hi()
     except Exception as e:
       ErrorHandler(e)
```

ErrorHandling.py:

```
def ErrorHandler(e):
  try:
    raise e
  except ZeroDivisionError: 
      print("zero")
  except FileNotFoundError:
      print("one")
  except FileExistsError:
      print("two")
  except Exception:
      print("three")
```

Comment: You don't need a try/except again, just catch the error, and pass it to a function.

Comment: @0xInfection Fair, but this might have been easier for them to understand as well since they're newer to Python. EDIT: After reading your answer, it's also easy to understand so as I was.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your question, you can do something like this:

Have your main code in `code.py` with contents:

```py
from exceptions import HandleExceptions

a = 5

try:
    if a/0 == 2:
        print('divided by zero') # obviously won't reach here
except Exception as e:
    HandleExceptions(e)
```

And have a `exceptions.py` with the following:

```py
def HandleExceptions(x):
    if isinstance(x, ZeroDivisionError):
        print('Dividing by zero not allowed')
    if isinstance(x, FileNotFoundError):
        print('File not found')
    ...
```

I hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it makes me more understand about python XD

Comment: I think it would make sense to use `elif` and end with an else which raises x to make sure unhandled exception are not dropped